# Put yarn nodemanager in maintenance

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, cloudera

I'm a part of a team that is running hadoop cloudera 5.13 implementation.

I am wondering if there is a way to set yarn nodemanagers in maintenance, thus running it renaming containers but not accept any new ones?

I do not have the cloudera enterprise solution.

Tried to find something good with the cli tool yarn rmadmin but was unable to do so.

Or is the only thing I can do shutdown the nodemanager and have my users containers die?

Comment: You don't need cloudera enterprise to use cloudera manager. If you shutdown a Node manager, the resource manager is responsible for for rescheduling the tasks elsewhere

Comment: @cricket_007 yes RM would restart the job on a new NM but i much rather would like to set the node in maintenance just as you can in LSF, vmware and so on to be able to block no jobs to the host and then shut it down when all jobs are done or when me as a admin got time for it.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called `Graceful decommissioning`.

In [YARN (MR2 Included) Properties in CDH 5.9.0](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/properties/5-9-x/topics/cm_props_cdh590_yarn_mr2included_.html) the property `yarn.resourcemanager.nodemanager-graceful-decommission-timeout-secs` allows you to control how many seconds the NM will wait on existing containers to finish before decommissioning.

The main design JIRA is:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-914 - (Umbrella) Support graceful decommission of nodemanager

Comment: Yes that was it thanks! I also looked around some and found https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/GracefulDecommission.html that also talks a bit on how to actually trigger the graceful decommission.